# Autofac - IHTTPClientFactory multithreading

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using NET Framework 4.7.2 with Autofac and Topshelf and I've implemented a HTTPClient like:

```
private static IContainer BuildContainer() {

    NameValueCollection anexiaADSettings = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("AnexiaADSettings");

    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddHttpClient("API", c => {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Settings["APIUrl"]);
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token " + Settings["APIToken"]);
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    });

    var providerFactory = new AutofacServiceProviderFactory();
    ContainerBuilder builder2 = providerFactory.CreateBuilder(services);

    //Builder Settings

    var container = builder2.Build();

    return container;

}
```

In my Worker Class my constructor looks like:

```
private readonly ILogger _log;
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

public LDAP(ILogger log, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory) {
    this._log = log;
    this._clientFactory = clientFactory;
}
```

And I'm calling my httpClient in a multithreading foreach loop with the following parameters:

```
var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient("API");
test= await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Models.GSObject>(uri);
```

The problem is, that the foreach loop gets started multiple times, but apparently there is only one instance of my httpClient active. If i execute the methode with 10 threads, the GetFromJsonAsync just runs sequentially. If the first call has been executed, it will go over to the next call and so on.
Shouldn't the httpClient gets the same amount of instances as I trigger the foreach loop?

EDIT:
Thats the current loop which is executed with a maximum of 10 threads:

```
        var taskThrottler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 10);
        var compareTasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var User in Users.data.data) {

            await taskThrottler.WaitAsync();

            compareTasks.Add(
                Task.Run(async () => {
                    try {
                        await _helper.CompareUsersAsync(_settings, adUsers, gsUser.identifier);
                    }
                    finally {
                        taskThrottler.Release();
                    }
                })
            );
        }
```

The CompareUsersAsync methode looks like:

```
    public async Task CompareUsersAsync(Settings settings, List<Models.ADUser> adUsers, string identifier) {

        var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient("API");
        
        try {
            string uri = "api/request.json/" + identifier;

            
            Models.GSADUser gsUser = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Models.GSADUser>(uri);

//Removed the rest of the code.
```

Comment: No, you should have 1 instance of HttpClient which will open multiple socket connections towards the server you are trying to reach. If you need multiple instances of HTTP client, search for named or typed HTTP client

Comment: You aren't showing the most important part: The code that actually makes the requests. You say something about a `foreach`, but I see no code. Also, I see no code using "multithreading" in there.

Comment: You're right. The correct question would be "Why do my httpClient only opens one socket and not multiple?"

Comment: @Andy I've added the corresponding code snippets. Let's say if I input a Console.WriteLine above the "_clientFactory.CreateClient("API")" line, than I see that my methode is executed 10 times. But if I add a Console.WriteLine under the GetFromJsonAsync request, I can see, that it's gonna be executed sequentially and I dont know why.
Additionally, there is only one active connection in netstat.

Comment: You need to read up on how connection pooling works: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core

Comment: The long and short of it is: You are doing everything correctly. I don't see anything in your code that is anti-pattern to `IHttpClientFactory`. The only thing that looks goofy to me is the use of `Task.Run`.

Comment: @Andy thank you for your assessment. I'm using the exact same code in a .NET Core Project and it's working fine so I thought there is maybe a difference between .NET Core und .NET Framework I've missed.

Comment: You should try to strive for organically asynchronous code. `HttpClient` is naturally/organically asynchronous. By using `Task.Run`, you break that pattern. I don't see a reason to use that, especially since you are using a semaphore to limit requests. This is how you should be doing it: https://pastebin.com/icFm8uNF

Comment: @Andy thank you very much! Unfortunately it results in the same behaviour as before. Only one socket will be used.

Comment: Instead of using named clients, try pulling clients right from `IHttpClientFactory` using the `CreateClient()` method without a name. So replace `var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient("API");` with `var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();`. Do not set `DefaultRequestHeaders()` on those clients though. Use `HttpClient::SendAsync()` with a `HttpRequestMessage()` and set the headers in that object before calling `SendAsync()`

Comment: @Andy - I have tried it with this approach but it ended up with the same result. I don't know why the Client is using only one socket.

Comment: Did you read the article on `HttpClient` connection pooling from above? It's doing this to avoid socket starvation on your service. If you want to override this, then don't use `IHttpClientFactory`. Create a new `HttpClient` every time you want to make a request. But be forwarded that this will cause your service to run out of sockets if it gets hot.

Comment: Thanks Andy! Your link brought me to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The default maximum value for connections to the same server is set to two. If you want to increase this value, you've to define a ServicePointManager like:

```
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddHttpClient("EngineAPI", c => {
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("URL");
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token " + settings["APIToken"]);
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        });
```

In this case, a maximum of 20 connections to the same endpoint are allowed.